# bxSlider - Wrong pause between slides when using pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

I'm running the latest version of **[Bxslider](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4)** (4.2.14), everything works great except for the pager.

**When using the pager to switch between slides, pause is much shorter than it should be:**

[image: bxSlider Pager Pause issue]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/Bruno42/smvhe3o4/7/**
2. When Slide #2 appears wait ~3-4 seconds
3. Switch back to Slide #1 by clicking on the pager
4. Pause should then last 5 seconds (like during the "auto" mode), but instead it lasts only 1-2 seconds

I think the Pause countdown should be **resetted** to 5 seconds every time a slide is selected using the Pager.

I spent a while trying to figure out a solution in the `clickPagerBind()` function in jquery.bxslider.js by using `clearInterval(slider.interval);` to fix this, however it did not work (slider gets stuck after that).

**Code used to load bxSlider** (also available on my **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bruno42/smvhe3o4/7/)**):

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 800,
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'full',
    autoHover: false,
    auto: true,
    stopAuto: false,
    stopAutoOnClick: false,
    speed: 1000,
    pause: 5000,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    controls: false,
});
```

I would really appreciate your help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `speed: 1000` might be too fast for the transition to complete and for `startAuto()` and `stopAuto()` methods to start or end. In order to control what methods are called during transition we can use a callback from the [bxSlider API](https://bxslider.com/options/). Make a custom function and call it on either `onSlideAfter` or `onSlideBefore`. The following demo calls `function pagerFix()` `onSlideAfter`:

```
function pagerFix($bx, prv, nxt) {
  bx.stopAuto(true);
  bx.goToSlide(nxt);
  bx.stopAuto(false);
  bx.startAuto(true);
}
```

When initializing `.bxSlider()` make sure you reference it so you can call the methods.

```
let bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(...
```

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/8meyb6wt/)

(uses `onSlideBefore`)

#### Demo

(uses `onSlideAfter`)

```js
let bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 800,
  auto: true,
  speed: 1000,
  pause: 5000,
  controls: false,
  onSlideAfter: pagerFix
});

function pagerFix($bx, prv, nxt) {
  bx.stopAuto(true);
  bx.goToSlide(nxt);
  bx.stopAuto(false);
  bx.startAuto(true);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<ul class="bxslider" style="width: 800px; height: 250px;">
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=1"></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=2"></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=3"></li>
  <li><img src="https://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=4"></li>
</ul>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Love this elegant solution, made my day ;-) Thank you so much @zer00ne!